# Jira: Team management for a ticket

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

My boss come with a very unique requirement, below is the explanation.

> Imagine there is **10 user for a particular project team**.

And the work flow is like

> **Documenting** -> **Review** -> **Publish**

Now, the requirement is like below.

If I create Ticket with Summary "*Version 1.0 Documents*" with the above explained workflow, then it should also allow us facility to manager for user regarding each state of workflow like

Documenting assign to User A

Review Assign to User B

Publish Assign to User C

Note: I know I can assign ticket to individual user while changing state, but I want something pre-planned so as soon as I change status of ticket it will automatically assign to user.

**I know I can do this** using [post action of transaction](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-automatically-change-the-assignee-when-transitioning-the-workflow-705954603.html) **but** what I want is, the assignee should be specified at creation of ticket as the same workflow going to use by many project and ticket, and every project will have different team

> So , I need something add-on which allow me to manage team for each ticket.

Also, User C should be able to see his/her upcoming work if ticket is in any previous state i,e Documenting or review.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should create account role for this and group to each department/team for their flow. you can use account role for separating their works then the department/team is useful for which members/users can see the particular issue/ticket. we already build something like this we have 3 account roles each ticket so i can say this is possible. if you still have question just let me know thanks.